# Force all files (exe and dll) replacements after OS restarting in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

In a need to our online update applications, I would like, from InnoSetup, **to replace all my files (exe and dll) after restarting the machine.**

I used the `restartreplace` property but this one replaces the dlls that are not in use.

My question is:
Is there an easy way to force all my files (used or locked) to be updated after restarting the machine?